# Spring Lombok Slf4j multiple log files based on log level

Tags: java, spring, logback, slf4j, lombok

I'm developing a Spring Boot Backend Service. For logging I'm currently using Lombok with Slf4j and Logback. Now i would like to log to different files based on the log level. I know how to do this with a custom logback (XML) configuration and multiple loggers, however it would be nice to do this with the one logger automatically provided by Lombok and Slf4j.
Thanks in advance!